# How to change TextBox's Background color?

Tags: c#, .net, wpf

I got C# code that is like:

```
if(smth == "Open")
{
    TextBox.Background = ???
}
```

How to change TextBox's background color?

Comment: Which TextBox class? Winforms? WPF? Other?

Comment: sorry, forgot to add that its WPF, already working! thanks so much guys :)

Answer (score 23, accepted):

If it's WPF, there is a collection of colors in the static class `Brushes`.

```
TextBox.Background = Brushes.Red;
```

Of course, you can create your own brush if you want.

```
LinearGradientBrush myBrush = new LinearGradientBrush();
myBrush.GradientStops.Add(new GradientStop(Colors.Yellow, 0.0));
myBrush.GradientStops.Add(new GradientStop(Colors.Orange, 0.5));
myBrush.GradientStops.Add(new GradientStop(Colors.Red, 1.0));
TextBox.Background = myBrush;
```

Comment: what are the namespaces to be used for GradientStops

Comment: Dont forget to use System.Windows.Media instead of System.Drawing namespace.

Comment: this doesn't work well, the background disappears when you put mouse over the field

Answer (score 21):

In WinForms and WebForms you can do:

```
txtName.BackColor = Color.Aqua;
```

Answer (score 6):

webforms;

```
TextBox.Background = System.Drawing.Color.Red;
```

Answer (score 3):

in web application in .cs page

```
   txtbox.Style.Add("background-color","black");
```

in css specify it by using backcolor property

Answer (score -3):

It is `txtName.BackColor = System.Drawing.Color.Red;`

one can also use `txtName.BackColor = Color.Aqua;`
which is the same as `txtName.BackColor = System.Color.Aqua;`

Only Problem with System.color is that it does not contain a definition for some basic colors especially white, which is important cause usually textboxes are white;

Answer (score -3):

Setting textbox backgroundcolor with multiple colors on single click.

Note:- using HTML and Javscript.

< input id="ClickMe_btn" onclick="**setInterval(function () { ab() }, 3000)**;" type="button" value="ClickMe" />

var arr, i = 0;
      arr = ["Red", "Blue", "Green", " Orange ", "Purple", "Yellow", "Brown", "Lime", "Grey"]; // We provide array as input.

```
    function ab()
     {   document.getElementById("Text").style.backgroundColor = arr[i];
          window.alert(arr[i]);
          i++;
     }
```

Note: You can change milliseconds, with setInterval 2nd parameter.